# Get DNS entry of localhost for service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, service, dns

For a IIS hosted service I have to get the full address of the local machine.

In the Web.config that value is perfectly configured

```
<services>
     <service name="MyService.Service.MyService">
       <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MexFlatWsdlBehavior"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
         name="TpsNotification" bindingNamespace="http://org.com/MyService/2014/11"
         contract="MyService.Service.ISomeEndpoint">
         <identity>
           <dns value="THESERVER.myorg.net" />
         </identity>
       </endpoint>
       <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MexFlatWsdlBehavior"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
         name="TpsPluginFramework" bindingNamespace="http://org.com/MyService/2014/11"
         contract="MyService.Service.IOtherEndpoint">
         <identity>
           <dns value="THESERVER.myorg.net" />
         </identity>
       </endpoint>
       <host>
         <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="https://THESERVER.myorg.net:443/MyService.svc" />
         </baseAddresses>
       </host>
     </service>
</services>
```

Any of *dns value* or *baseAddress* would be perfectly fine.
But I see no way to get to that value from IIS.

I tried `ConfigurationManager` and `WebConfiguration` and `HostingEnvironment`.

Furthermore I tried

```
var hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
```

which works for some cases, but not for this server, because the configured address is not the primary dns address, which is returned here.

Any options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the config file in to a linq to xml doc, then you can query it all you want ...

```
var config = XDocument.Load("Web.Config");
var baseAddress = config.Elements("baseAddresses")
    .Elements()
    .First()
    .Attribute("baseAddress")
    .Value;
```

If all else fails, use the brute force approach :)

Another option might be ...
Since you are in the context of a request to a server why not use the request object ...

```
var host = Request.Url.Host;
```

That was simpler!

Comment: This is during configuation / startup. There is no OperationContext, HttpContext, Request, ...